# Using the word "hole" in formal contexts

Tags: word-choice

> (a) There were *holes* in  Shakespeare's erudition.

In contexts like the above, well-educated Italians, as far as I know, wouldn't use the word "holes" because it seems a bit informal.

A more appropriate Italian word would be *[lacune](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lacune#Noun_4)*, which, according to the dictionary I use, is translated with "gap" (also cf. English *[lacune](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lacune#Noun)*, *[lacuna](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lacuna#Noun)*,  *lacunes*,  and *[lacunae](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lacunae)*).

In English it appears that a more formal version of the above sentence is:

> (b) There were *gaps* in  Shakespeare's erudition.

So, is (b) more formal than (a)? Or, is there a more appropriate word to use in the place of "holes" to have a more formal sentence? Or, lastly, is this not a real problem that it make sense to think about?

Comment: I don't think this is a matter of formal/informal - it's just that idiomatically we don't normally speak of "holes" in things like *education, employment history, knowledge*, etc. *Gaps* would be a common choice, but I must say it sounds odd to describe *erudition* like that anyway. It's an abstract concept that we might metaphorically reference as "broad" or "vast", but to me it seems a stretch too far to imagine it as some kind of sheet with holes in it ("gaps" evokes *the passage of time*, so it works for *education* better than for *erudition*).

Comment: I don't think _lacunae_ would be a good choice at all; I'd use _holes_ before _lacunae_, as _lacuna_ is quite rare and not widely known.

Comment: @Fumble: We may not use "holes" in that context, but we do speak of "holes" in things like _arguments, defense, plans_, and _stories_.

Comment: @J.R.: Indeed - though [certainly with **arguments**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gaps+in+the+argument%2Choles+in+the+argument&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), **gaps** have always been more common (with **plans**, it's about even).

Comment: @Fumble: In my lifetime and on my continent, the [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gaps+in+the+argument%2Choles+in+the+argument&year_start=1970&year_end=2005&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) is a virtual dead heat. More importantly, though, conversationally, I believe I've heard _hole_ more often. (Data isn't as readily accessible, although two Google searches favored "hole in the argument" by more than 3 to 1. Of course, I didn't bother to examine the millions of results with scrutiny – but it did make me wonder if this might be a BrE/AmE thing.)

Comment: @J.R.: There does indeed seem to be a UK/US split here. Surprisingly, for such a disputatious bunch, you Americans apparently don't [pick holes in](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pick+holes+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) things even half as much as we Brits!

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, but we [*poke* holes in](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pick+holes+in%2Cpoke+holes+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) things! :) As an American I would use *gap* to refer to a *gap in knowledge*, but for all other similar things I would always use *hole* ("holes in your story", etc.). I agree that it sounds odd to use either for *erudition*, though I can't put my finger on why.

Comment: @WendiKidd As a fellow American, I feel like a *hole in your story* is an inconsistency, while a *gap in your story* is an unaccounted-for period of time. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: @WendiKidd: Maybe it's just because *erudition* normally means ***profound** scholarly knowledge*, so it feels unnatural to use the word in contexts where you're calling attention to the things someone *doesn't* know. *"I have limited knowledge"* sounds fine, but *"I have limited erudition"* just sounds weird.

Comment: @Daniel: In my first comment where I said *"gaps" evokes the passage of time*, I meant that normally when we use *gaps* metaphorically, it's in relation to *temporal continuity*. Hence [Arlo Guthrie's 1997 re-recording of *Alice's Restaurant*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice's_Restaurant) is explained as being responsible for the *18.5 minute **gap** in the Nixon Tapes* (a missing section in a tape is normally referred to as a ***gap***, not a ***hole***). Metaphoric *holes* are usually crucial parts of a *pattern* that are missing, not chronological discontinuities.

Answer (score 1):

Well, no one has answered so far. I'm going to give it a shot.

- "There were **inconsistencies** in Shakespeare's erudition."

[inconsistencies](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inconsistencies):*There were many inconsistencies in your proposal*

or

- "Shakespeare's erudition was **not wholly complete**."

  *Wholly* has the the same sound as "holey"

[wholly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wholly):*The accusation is wholly without foundation*